# Understanding こともあるが in this context

Tags: grammar

そう、彼女。
あえてレーナが伏せた**こともあるが**、女性だとは思っていなかったらしい。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.4　─アンダー・プレッシャー─
安里アサト

A woman called シデン・イーダ was introducing herself to the speaker, who only knew her by name (but never met the woman) beforehand and thought that シデン・イーダ was a man. Partly because レーナ kept her gender secret to the speaker.

Does this bold こともあるが mean "although partly because…"? Is the こともあるが a variant of the grammar construction こともあって, as explained in this link?

https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/26539117.html

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct. こともあるが and こともあって are roughly interchangeable (except that the former can sound fairly blunt in speech because of が). You would also see ～こともありますけど, ～こともあるけれど, ～こともあるだろうが, ～こともなくはないでしょうが, and so on.