# もある in this context?

Tags: reading-comprehension

因藤の代ってなんかキラキラしてますよね

彼の性格もあると思うけど

Context: A couple of girls are checking a colleague. They comment that his generation/age range is really sparky. Then the other girl adds this. But I don't quite get what could she mean? "He also has a personality?" Is there some hidden meaning?

Comment: Related or duplicate [Understanding こともあるが in this context](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96026)